# Symfony serialization: changing default DateTimeNormalizer format

Tags: symfony, datetime, serialization, normalization

I am trying to serialize an entity class which has some \DateTime fields. Everything works fine, but \DateTime objects are converted to string using the following format: "2019-10-21T01:05:12+00:00", while I would like to get just the date part: "2019-10-21".

Symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#normalizers) mentions default format but doesn't explain how to configure it:

> **DateTimeNormalizer** This normalizer converts DateTimeInterface objects (e.g. DateTime and DateTimeImmutable) into strings. By default, it uses the RFC3339 format.

Is it possible to change the default DateTime normalization format and how?

**Entity class:**

```
class Fact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     * @Groups({"api"})
     */
    private $created_on;
}
```

**Normalization example:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class FactController extends AbstractController
{
    private $serializer;

    public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    public function view($id)
    {
        ....   
        $data = array(
            'fact' => $this->serializer->normalize($fact, null, ['groups'=> 'api']),
        );
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that '$context' array is passed down to normalize() function of each supported Normalizer. Built-in Normalizers define array keys they accept and their default values.

The relevant key in my case is `'datetime_format'`, which defaults to `\DateTime::RFC3339`. Format must be the one accepted by `\DateTime::format()` and `\DateTime::createFromFormat()` methods - these functions are used for normalization / denormalization.

Correct usage in my case is:

```
    public function view($id)
    {
        ....   
        $data = array(
            'fact' => $this->serializer->normalize($fact, null, ['groups'=> 'api',
                                                                 'datetime_format' => 'Y-m-d']),
        );
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I forgot that i can add more elementsto the context array, coudn't find this on the documentation, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668037/611527) in another question. Solution is:

```yaml
services:
   serializer.normalizer.datetime:
       class: ‘Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer
       arguments
           -
               !php/const Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP’
       tags:
           - { name: serializer.normalizer, priority: -910 }
```

Priority is taken from the original service, so, this solution will not have any side effects.